# What is the に particle in 他に doing

Tags: particle-に

> 他にいいものがたくさんあるけど、やっぱりこれにする。
>
> "There are a lot of other good things, but as I thought I'll go with this one"

What is the に particle doing here? Is it turning 他 into an adjective?
I understand that いいもの means good thing but I can't figure out why they wrote 他にいいもの instead of 他いいもの.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[他]{ほか} is a noun. And it can be used alone as a noun; example from 明鏡国語辞典:

> 「ここには[見当]{みあ}たらないから、どこか**[他]{ほか}を**[捜]{さが}そう。」

It can also be used adverbially; from 明鏡国語辞典:

> 「[会長]{かいちょう}**[他]{ほか}**[三名]{さんめい}が[出席]{しゅっせき}」
>   「[文書]{ぶんしょ}をもってする**[他]{ほか}**、[口頭]{こうとう}でも[説明]{せつめい}する」

Since 他 is a noun, 他**の** can modify nouns / noun phrases adjectivally... like 「[別]{べつ}の + [部屋]{へや}」「[右]{みぎ}の + [箱]{はこ}」 etc., as in:

> **[他]{ほか}の**[人]{ひと} -- other people / someone else
>   **他の**もの -- other things / something else

And 他**に** can modify verbs adverbially... like 「別に + する (= 分ける)」「[左右]{さゆう}に + [振]{ふ}る」 etc., as in the examples from 明鏡国語辞典:

> 「何か**他に**[必要]{ひつよう}なものはありませんか」(Do you need anything other than that?)
>   「[釣]{つ}りの**他に**、カメラが好きだ」(Besides fishing, I like taking photos.)

So, going back to your sentence...

> **他に**いいものがたくさんあるけど・・・

The 他に ("other than that" / "beside that") modifies the verb ある ("exist" → "There are") adverbially. So it literally means "Although there are a lot of good things other than that...", hence the translation "There are a lot of other good things, but...".

---

> instead of 他いいもの

[他]{ほか} is a noun, so you can't just connect a noun 「他」 + a noun phrase 「いいもの」.
You'd say 「他の + いいもの」 to *literally* say "other + good things".

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, you always clears the matter plus insights other things that i may not know or remember, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

他にいいもの is better than 他のいいもの. Other expressions are 他にも, 他のもの. 他に is an adverb, the meaning of [他に](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AB) are besides, without. So に add at 他.

Comment: What does 他 alone means? Like 静か is quiet and it becomes the adverb quietly, 嬉しい as happy and then 嬉しく as happily. But other than becomes otherly? It does not make sense to me, sorry. Could you explain it a bit further? Thanks

Comment: 他 is never used alone. Also 静 of 静か. "otherly" is very good.

Comment: So I just consider it an adverb, period? It's a bit odd when I think in that using Portuguese or English logic but so far learning Japanese I've noticed that many things have a whole different logic. Thank you for the help :)