# Understanding the に in 「私達家族の他にもたくさん家族が来ています」

Tags: particle-に

In

> 私達家族の他**に**もたくさん家族が来ています
>
> Even (も) outside of our family, many other families are coming.

1. Why is there a に after 私達家族の他?
2. Would the sentence still make sense if it were omitted?

My best guess at (1) is that the sentence might mean "many other familes are coming *towards* (に) our family"?

Comment: Are you missing a の between 私達 and 家族?

Comment: @user3856370 It's from [here](https://youtu.be/Y7sxC472DbI?t=266), which doesn't include a の between them?

Comment: 他 is a noun, and 他に is adverbial usage of that noun. If you searched for "他に", you would have found e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39619/56758 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82262/56758. Sentence would be ungrammatical without に here. NOUNの他に means "besides NOUN, outside of NOUN", に is not a case particle ("towards") here.